# Prevent process from changing its process group id (`setpgid`)

Tags: linux, unix, capability, apparmor

Is there any way in Linux to prevent a process from modifying its process group ID, i.e. by calling `setpgid`? I need to do so because I am creating a sandbox, and I want to be able to kill a process and all of its children after n seconds. I am identifying the children from the process group id, so I need to make sure this value cannot be changed.

There is someting called `CAP_SETGID` but I think this refers to the process' user-group id, i.e. what is set by `setgid` which is something different from `setpgid`?

Comment: You're right that `CAP_SETGID` is very different from what you are seeking.  I don't think there's a way to do what you'd like to do, but I live to be proved wrong.